# Does a SAML application store the state while creating a request (Okta's document says it doesn't)?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

Okta's official document states that a SAML Service Provider does not store any state:

https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/saml/#planning-for-saml

> The Service Provider doesn't know if the Identity Provider will ever complete the entire flow. Because of this, the Service Provider doesn't maintain any state of any authentication requests generated.

However, I also read that the SAML Application will generate a request ID which is unique to that particular request. And the SAML response will contain this same request ID which the application will use to figure out which request it corresponds to.

There is a contradiction between Okta's doc and the SAML concept. The application is storing the state. Is Okta's doc inaccurate or am I missing some concept over here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Okta's document is misleading. As you say, one of the checks that a service provider should make is that the InResponseTo field in the SAML response matches the SAML authn request's ID. This is essentially state information the SP must remember so it can perform this check when the SAML response is received. Our SAML implementation certainly maintains state information and I would imagine most, if not all, implementations would.

Comment: Ah! That explains. Thanks for clearing this up!